# Why can't i log in on Unity?

Tags: lightdm

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 with Unity.
Whenever I log in into my computer, the screen becomes black, then purple (that dark ubuntu-color) and that switches a few times. Between that the screen shortly shows a nvidia-logo. Then it switches back to the login-screen.

What is wrong with my PC? What can i do? I hope you could help me...

PS: Sorry for my bad english, I'm no native speaker.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm sorry for opening a new question. I just didn't know what to type into the search. The other answers helped me, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting, from a tty, the .Xauthority file.

To log into a tty, press Ctrl+Alt+F6 and insert your username and password, and then:

```
sudo rm -v .Xauthority
```

Try then to log-in again, you can go back to the login with:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: After executing this command, it opens a window after logging-in, that says: "Could not update ICEauthority file /home/user/.ICEauthority" It also shows a button to log out

Comment: OK, i tried to change the owner (chown) of the file .ICEauthority and it worked. Thanks a lot :)